# Force include for intellisense in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intellisense, undefined-symbol

I'm working with a codebase in which (for complex and unchangeable reasons) class header files do not #include our basic math library headers. The math headers are included from the PCH header (hence before the class header files), so everything compiles fine, but intellisense freaks out on the math types used in the headers.

Is there some way to force intellisense to include a certain header when parsing? Like the /FI option to the compiler, but without affecting actual compilation.

Comment: There's no conceivable reason that the IS parser would have a problem with this, it also parses the pre-compiled header file.  Since the #include for stdafx.h is at the top of every .cpp file.  You are doing something non-standard, impossible to guess what that might be.

Comment: The intellisense errors are in the header, not the cpp. There is no PCH include in the header.

Comment: A .cpp file in the project has to #include that .h before the IS parser can see it.  Sounds like you added .h files to your project and made them look like .cpp files, not sure how you'd do that.

Comment: There's an option to do exactly that for makefile projects... I don't see it for normal projects, though. Sounds like a good feature request for VC13 :)